# Focus on lastordefault, but handle call open new window

Tags: integration-testing, window-handles

I am writing unit test with c# and I want to focus last opened page in new window. But when I use this:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> handles = wDriver.WindowHandles;
String myWindowHandle = handles.LastOrDefault();
```

Windows handle opens one more window. I do not need that opening or maybe i can focus on window by URL or etc?

Comment: unit tests usually don't care of system dependency, seems not a unit test

Comment: I just need to know, how to focus one of opened window. Or how to do that window handle do not open new window.

Comment: Do not need help. I just was forget to set page before wDriver :)
Now my code looks like that:

`PDF.Click();
                                
                                ReadOnlyCollection<string> handles = ip.wDriver.WindowHandles;
                                
                                foreach(var h in ip.wDriver.WindowHandles)
                                {
                                    if (h != ip.wDriver.CurrentWindowHandle)
                                    {
                                        ip.wDriver.SwitchTo().Window(h);

...`